# I want to use jira-rest-java-client sdk to access test cases of my Jira, but I'm not sure how to

Tags: java, sdk, jira

My pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-rest-java-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>

        </dependency>
```

I want to access one of my test case XX-T1234, here are my code.I got 404 error, I'm not sure my sdk and code are right.

```java
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClient;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.ProjectRestClient;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClientFactory;
import com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.domain.Issue;
import java.net.URI;


String jiraUrl = "https://mockrun-jira.xxxxxx.com";
        String username = "xxx";
        String token = "<MASK>";
        String issueKey = "XX-T1234"; // The key of the issue you want to retrieve

          Issue issue = client.getIssueClient().getIssue(issueKey).claim();
System.out.println("Issue summary: " + issue.getSummary());
```

- Changed the code
- Search document of Jira

Answer (score 0):

The reason that you can't find your test case is because test cases aren't a core part of Jira.

From looking at the test case id in your sample code (`XX-T1234`) it looks to me like you might be using something like Zephyr Scale (formerly known as TM4J, formerly known as Adaptavist Test Management / ATM).

This is a Jira plugin and so won't be supported by the Jira REST Client library.

My recommendation, if you're wanting to interact with Zephyr Scale is to check out their Javadocs: https://support.smartbear.com/zephyr-scale-server/javadocs/9.15.1/